# load list of links one at a time as soon as previous finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Similar to [Show a list of links in an iframe one at a time with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357094/show-a-list-of-links-in-an-iframe-one-at-a-time-with-jquery) but without the setTimeout function - as i would rather start the next fetch once the previous document as finished loading.

I'm a noob with javascript and even more so with jquery, but here was my first shot:

```
links = ["http://example1.com","http://example2.com","http://example3.com"]
function loadNext(x){
  if ( x < links.length ){
    $('#target').load('links[x]');
    $('#target').ready(function(){
        x++;
        loadNext(x);
    });
  };
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.loader').click(function(){
    loadNext(0);
  });
});

</script>
<div id="bd" role="main">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="loader">Start loading</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```

I can't really see why this wouldn't work.  The logic seems correct at least. on click fire a function with index 0 passed in, then load that array value (full url) in id="target " and once that target is ready run the function again.  Clicking doesn't appear to even load the first target, much less iterate (i had expected it to redirect the first click until i figured out the proxy stuff...)

Comment: What is 'links[x]'? It is wrong. Where is `links` defined?

Comment: links IS defined,  just an array.  that has been verified to be correct with the document.write method beyond my goals here (just as a test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `links` defined somewhere in the code. Try this which calls `loadNext` once the previous load is complete using `load` method's callback feature.

```
function loadNext(x){
  if ( x < links.length ){
    $('#target').load(links[x], function(){
        loadNext(x++);
    });
  }
}
```

With above code every load will overwrite the previous content in `#target`. If you want to retain that then use this.

```
function loadNext(x){
  if ( x < links.length ){
    $('#target').append($('<div />').load(links[x], function(){
        loadNext(x++);
       })
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:**

If you are trying to access external urls using `load` then it is not going to work because of cross domain access restrictions. But there are certain ways to get content from external site using JSONP, YQL etc.

Take a look at this link 
http://icant.co.uk/articles/crossdomain-ajax-with-jquery/using-yql.html

Comment: wont `x++` evaluate to a non-incremented x ? maybe use pre-increment

Comment: I think the initial value of `x` is 0 so post increment is correct.

Comment: Yes, links is defined - just an array of, well.. links.  I was able to get the app working using window.open and setTimeout - so i know that isn't the problem. But i've tried your suggestion here (the first one) and found that it did not work - nothing happens when i click :(   Note too that the links are full/external URL's - not sure if that matters here.

Comment: If the links are external urls then it will not work because of cross domain access restrictions. You will have to use some other way to achieve this.

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: thanks for the link.  I'm going to go ahead and try pushing forward with this approach using the doAjax(links[x]) function in that link rather than load(links[x]) and see how far i get.  thank you.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli it doesn't matter what the initial value of x is: `loadNext(x++)` is equivalent to `loadNext(x)`.. post-increment evaluates to the current value of x and increments x after the fact.. when the function is called again `x` is a new variable in a new stack frame

Comment: Yes, but next time when `loadNext(x)` is called, `x` is already incremented. I hope you understand this.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli if x were defined outside the function it would be different

Comment: @paislee - Yes, you are right if x is defined outside the funtion x++ will make a difference. I haven't swiped your code that is my alternative solution because OP didn't mention that the content has to append or replace. Anyways +1 to you :)

Comment: @ShankarSangoli no problem see you around!

Answer (score 1):

The following improvements should help:

```
$('#target').append($("<div>").load(links[x], function() {
    loadNext(x+1);
});
```

- `load()` accepts a callback function as a parameter, which you should use
- `'links[x]'` is taken to be a URL, so remove the single quotes (assuming `links` exists)
- `load()` overwrites content of `#target`, so combine with `append()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're script is just not valid code. If `x` is supposed to be an array `if ( x < links.length )` is wrong. `load('links[x]')` is incorrect. `links` is not declared. You're calling the same function within the function and you have many unexpected `;`. And `ready()` is not what you think it is.
You'll have to rethink this whole thing I'm afraid.

Comment: links is defined as an array. I'll go ahead and edit the post to stop people from pointing that out. I've tried both load('links[x]') and load(links[x]) to no avail. x would be the index to be used/incremented and i've used firebug to verify the line ends.  as for ready working the way i think it does, that may be valid - but what *will* work for my goal then?